# jQuery: How to match non-adjacent sequence of classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use jQuery to match a series of non-adjacent siblings, but can't seem to get the selectors right.

Here's the problem:

I have a document with paragraphs and headings. The headings have class names such as `.one`, `.two`, `.three`, and `.five`.

I'd like to match all headings that show up in a specific pattern. For example: `.one`, `.one`, `.three`, `.five`. I'd like to match this sequence regardless of the number of other headings in between each one.

Here's another way to state the goal. Starting from the top of the document, I want to:

1. Find the first `.one` heading that appears.
2. Then match the next `.one` heading
3. Then match the next `.three` heading
4. Then match the next `.five` heading

Repeat

1. Find the next `.one` heading
2. Then match the next `.one` heading
3. Then match the next `.three` heading
4. Then match the next `.five` heading

Repeat again until the end of the document.

I got pretty close using `nextAll()`:

```
headings = $('.one').nextAll('.one, .three, .five').addBack();
headings.css('color', 'red');
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<h1 class="one">One</h1><!-- Select this -->
<p class="a">One</p>
<p class="b">One</p>
<p class="c">One</p>
<p class="d">One</p>

<h1 class="one">One</h1><!-- Select this -->
<p class="a">a</p>
<p class="b">b</p>

<h1 class="three">Three</h1><!-- Select this -->
<p class="a">a</p>
<p class="b">b</p>
<p class="c">c</p>

<h1 class="one">One</h1><!-- DON'T SELECT THIS -->
<p class="a">a</p>

<h1 class="four">Three</h1>
<p class="a">a</p>

<h1 class="five">Five</h1><!-- Select this -->
<p class="a">a</p>
<p class="b">b</p>
<p class="c">c</p>
<p class="d">d</p>
```

The problem is that it matches every instance of `.one`, when I only want the first two, not the third. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the JS fiddle of what I tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/n7B55/1/

Comment: Is "first two" an arbitrary criterion (based on a "specific sequence")? Or is there some logic behind deciding that you should select two, or some other number of `.one` elements?

Comment: I'm having problems seeing the logic in this, but maybe just `$('.one:lt(2), .three, .five').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: Yes, "first two" is arbitrary. For example, I may also one to match, `.one`, `.three`, `.one`, `.five`, without matching the second `.one` in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the goal is to be able to specify a pattern or order of headings, and match them through out the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array and `filter` method.

```
var selector = ['one', 'one', 'three', 'five'],
    i = 0;    

$('h1').filter(function() {
   var match = $(this).hasClass(selector[i]); 
   if (match) i++;
   i = i % selector.length;
   return match;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7BUd/